# Zxing QR Scanner Embeded disable beep sound

Tags: java, android, embedded, zxing

I have integrated Zxing QR Scanner in my Android app using the instructions here:
https://github.com/journeyapps/zxing-android-embedded ( Adding aar dependency with Gradle)
Everything works great with the scanner but when the scan is succesfull and the phone media volume is not on mute the app generates a beep sound.
Can you help me disable that beep? 
Thank you!

Comment: Did you end up figuring out how to do this? I've run into the same issue.

Comment: Unfortunately not yet!I forgot about this issue as my app is a lot bigger and I solved other issues, I will look more into it and will post here if I solve it!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try this:

```
IntentIntegrator.forFragment(this) 
                .setBeepEnabled(false);
```

Answer (score 0):

In 
*zxing-android-embedded/zxing-android/src/com/google/zxing/client/android/CaptureActivity.java*
there is defined **private BeepManager beepManager;**

... Look around to mute it.

Comment: Hello, thank you for your answer!
I am using maven repository to integrate ZXing, so the library is downloaded and integrated when I compile my project . In this case I don't have access to the class you mentioned. 
Do you know any solution with my scenario?

Answer (score 0):

Disable it in the your Android device's Settings > Sound & Notification
https://code.google.com/p/zxing/issues/detail?id=337